Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process', while using NextAuth v5 and NextJs latest version
So I've tried to implement an authentication with Mongodb on my app, and after installing nextauth v5 (currently in beta), and trying to put any component or page on the "client side," my app would just crash, and nothing would work. I've tried to downgrade the versions nextauth and Mongodb, but still nothing happened, meanwhile I figured out some things:
(I also need to use useState, useEffect ect...)
1.
Here is the link for the code and how it works or just check down below this link
 import { signIn } from "@/auth.ts"
 
export function SignIn() {
  return (
    <form
      action={async () => {
        "use server"
        await signIn("google")
      }}
    >
      <button type="submit">Signin with Google</button>
    </form>
  )
} 


app would work like this because the component is generally not on client side only action function uses use server but after trying to add use state or use effect or generally just putting "use client" app would drop the error : Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'




error image
So on this image you can see this path (./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encrpytion/mongocrptd_manager.js) that leads to this : const { spawn } = require('child_process');
image of require('child_process')
I have no idea if I can somehow bypass this: it still pops up an error after I delete this requirement. I have no idea if there is any fix for this. Also you can check my repo link down below this:.
here is the link for github repo
i ve tried deleting the require for this 'child_process', downgrade all packages, using "client side" that caused the issue and obv didnt work..., also setting webpack childprocess to false didnt work...

you cannot usie child_process, fs like system libs on front end (Browser).
Next js supported server technology, you can use on that libs. I do not remember next js but its like them:
serverSideProps(){
//calling child_process
}

What I mean is that in your case, the library should only run on the server.


Yes but how can i use hooks and client side things like onClick functions ect without that messing up, go on download the repository and just put "use client" on /app/page.jsx and you will see that its not going to work at all

I am using next version 14.2 and next-auth version 5.0.0-beta.19
this is working for me
   "use client";

import React from "react";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
const LoginButton = () => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => signIn("google")}
      type="submit"
    >
      <i className="fab fa-google"></i>
      <span>Google</span>
    </button>
  );
};

export default LoginButton;


so i wonder whats the problem then if this works... have you tried adding mongodb connection to it?

hi sry for the late reply, hope it was solved with u.. yes I am using MongoDBAdapter and it is working fine

I fixed it just by downgrading to older version of next auth, i dont think this beta version is ready for all users yet
